# Moments of products of independent random variables: $E[ X^kY^k ]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, independence, moment-problem

If we are given that two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, I'm wondering if the rule:  $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ applies for any integer $k>0$, such that:

$E[X^kY^k] = E[X^k]E[Y^k]$.

Is this a straight forward result? or am I missing something fundamental?

Thanks for your comments / suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so are $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ where $f$ and $g$ are measurable.

Hence $X^k$ and $Y^k$ are independent. Hence, provided that they exist,

we have $$E[X^kY^k]=E[X^k]E[Y^k]$$

Comment: Great. Thanks for your quick reply. I didn't consider the independence of the distributions. Great! Thanks

Comment: How about the converse?  Under what conditions can we infer that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if we know $E[X^k Y^\ell] = E[X^k] E[Y^\ell]$ for all $k, \ell$?   (It's probably not wise to require $k = \ell$ here.

Comment: That's an interesting question, unfortunately, I don't know the result yet.